Using makecell without centering
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{table}
        
\centering
    \caption{PRNU for Figure 3-5}
\label{tab1}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \tabcolsep=0.4cm
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc} % four columns, alignment for each
    \toprule[1.5pt]
      \textbf {Figure} & \textbf{Evaluator} & \textbf{Original} & \textbf{SEID} & \textbf{FFT-wavelet}& \textbf{1D-GF}& \textbf{WLS-BF}\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
  Figure~\ref{fig3}& \makecell[c]{\\PRNU \\[2ex] MRD\\[2ex]}& \makecell[c]{\\0.3299 \\[2ex] 0.00$\%$\\[2ex]} & \makecell[c]{\\0.3283 \\[2ex] 1.08$\%$\\[2ex]} & \makecell[c]{\\0.3290 \\[2ex] 1.28$\%$\\[2ex]} & \makecell[c]{\\0.3282 \\[2ex] 1.19$\%$\\[2ex]} & \makecell[c]{\\0.3281 \\[2ex] 1.17$\%$\\[2ex]}\\\bottomrule[1.5pt]
    % Figure~\ref{fig4}& 0.4335 & 0.4318 & 0.4329 & 0.4321 & \textbf{0.4316}\\\hline
  %           Figure~\ref{fig5}& 0.3299 & 0.3283 & 0.3290 & 0.3282 & \textbf{0.3281}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


I'm trying to make a table using makecell, but the subsequent values are not centered, I'd like to ask for your help, thank you very much!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Please also make sure to add the code as text and not as image so we can copy it to reproduce your problem.

The code you posted in an answer should be an edit of your question.

But it is still not a minimal working example and therefore IMHO not really sufficient.

Slightly related: since it's easier to compare numbers that are vertically adjacent to each other, you should transpose your table.

You can vertically center the contents of the first column with respect to the two rows in the following columns using \multirow. No need for makecell here. In the following example, I also included a more compact version:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\centering
    \caption{PRNU for Figure 3-5}
\label{tab1}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \tabcolsep=0.4cm
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
      \textbf {Figure} & \textbf{Evaluator} & \textbf{Original} & \textbf{SEID} & \textbf{FFT-wavelet}& \textbf{1D-GF}& \textbf{WLS-BF}\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
  \multirow{2}{*}{Figure~\ref{fig3}}& PRNU & 0.3299 & 0.3283 & 0.3290 & 0.3282 & 0.3281 \\
                                    & MRD  & 0.00\% & 1.08\% & 1.28\% & 1.19\% & 1.17\% \\ \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}   
\centering
    \caption{PRNU for Figure 3-5}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
      Figure & Evaluator & Original & SEID & FFT-wavelet& 1D-GF& WLS-BF \\
\midrule
  \multirow{2}{*}{\ref{fig3}}& PRNU & 0.3299 & 0.3283 & 0.3290 & 0.3282 & 0.3281 \\
                                    & MRD  & 0.00\% & 1.08\% & 1.28\% & 1.19\% & 1.17\% \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

For improved alignment of the numbers, I also included a transposed example with siunitx:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\centering
    \caption{PRNU for Figure 3-5}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1.2]}}
    \toprule
      &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Figure~\ref{fig3}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Figure~\ref{fig4}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
   Evaluator   & {PRNU}  & {MRD \%} & {PRNU}  & {MRD \%} \\
\midrule 
   Original    & 0.3299  & 0.00     & 0.3299  & 0.00     \\ 
   SEID        & 0.3283  & 1.08     & 0.3283  & 1.08     \\  
   FFT-wavelet & 0.3290  & 1.28     & 0.3290  & 1.28     \\ 
   1D-GF       & 0.3282  & 1.19     & 0.3282  & 1.19     \\ 
   WLS-BF      & 0.3281  & 1.17     & 0.3281  & 1.17     \\ 
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks, I think your transposed table is very beautiful, but there is a problem, the AAS template I use to import your code directly will have problems, please ask you how to use it correctly in the AAS template, thank you very much!

@bonnlemadilinemilo: Since I don't know with template you use, nor the exact error messages you receive I unfortunately can't answer that. It's probably best if you ask a follow up question and include a complete MWE that allows others to reproduce the issue you have.

@bonnlemadilinemilo: Just a guess, but probably the following links contain some useful information: Clash between siunitx and AASTeX and AASTex Author guide: Column decimal alignment

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I took a liberty and move code from your answer to question

Note, code is just fragment. Please extend it to MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document which begin with \documentclass and end with \end{document}˙

Your problem has nothing common with longtable and overleaf (which is just an editor, so I delete those tags

from code fragment and question is not entirely clear to me if table contain evaluation just for one image or for three (if it is just for one, than the first column in table is superfluous).

As supplement to nice @leandriis answer (+1) I suggest you to try use  tblr table of tabularray  package. With it the table's code is more concise and clear:


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}   
¸   \centering
\caption{PRNU for figures 3 - 5}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} *{7}{c} @{}},
             cell{even[2]}{1} = {r=2}{},   
             cell{odd[3]}{3-Z} = {appto={\,\%}},   
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             }
    \toprule
Figure  & Evaluator 
                & Original  & SEID      & FFT-wavelet   & 1D-GF     & WLS-BF    \\
    \midrule
\ref{fig3}
        & PRNU  & 0.3299    & 0.3283    & 0.3290        & 0.3282    & 0.3281    \\
        & MRD   & 0.00      & 1.08      & 1.28          & 1.19      & 1.17      \\ 
    \addlinespace
\ref{fig4}
        & PRNU  & 0.3299    & 0.3283    & 0.3290        & 0.3282    & 0.3281    \\
        & MRD   & 0.00      & 1.08      & 1.28          & 1.19      & 1.17      \\ 
    \addlinespace
\ref{fig5}
        & PRNU  & 0.3299    & 0.3283    & 0.3290        & 0.3282    & 0.3281    \\
        & MRD   & 0.00      & 1.08      & 1.28          & 1.19      & 1.17      \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


IN the case, that table contain evaluation just for one figure, than you may consider the following suggestion:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}   
¸   \centering
\caption{PRNU for Figure \ref{fig3}}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} *{6}{c} @{}},
             cell{odd[3]}{2-Z} = {appto={\,\%}},   
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             }
    \toprule
Evaluator 
        & Original  & SEID      & FFT-wavelet   & 1D-GF     & WLS-BF    \\
    \midrule
PRNU    & 0.3299    & 0.3283    & 0.3290        & 0.3282    & 0.3281    \\
MRD     & 0.00      & 1.08      & 1.28          & 1.19      & 1.17      \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


